# How to deploy Ionic 4 app to Github pages?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-cli

I have a problem deploying Ionic 4 app to Github pages.
I tried follwing a tutorial for uploading Angular app but it does not work. It keeps throwing errors of all kinds.
Does anyone can help? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: By deploy you mean you want to push your code to your github repo? This should not be too angular specific. What exactly you are doing can you list steps?

Comment: I have a github repo with Ionic code. I want to create a subpage to my Github pages account in order to deploy the app as a web project. For example, my github pages account is user-account.github.io and I want to view the app as user-account.github.io/TheApp.  I want to have a preview of the project in github pages. It has to compile the typescript code because these pages can contain only plain html, css and javascript. I am using ionic-cli for building the project.

Comment: I see is there specific reason you want to host your static website with Github? I personally would recommend you separate concerns and use each service that was designed for their purposes - github - code repo, use firebase hosting as easy to use and super easy to deploy static web site hosting service. See this guide: https://www.joshmorony.com/hosting-an-ionic-pwa-with-firebase-hosting/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how to use angular-cli-ghpages with Ionic 4:

1. Create your Ionic project (`ionic start MyApp blank`)
2. Install the plugin: `npm i angular-cli-ghpages --save`
3. Connect your project with your github repository.
4. Navigate in the terminal to your project directory and execute `ionic build --prod -- --base-href https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME.github.io/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/`, what will create the `www` folder, which is comparable to the `dist` folder for Angular. It also sets your github page domain as  base href in index.html.
5. Then run the plugin: `npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir=www`. The flag at the end points to the `www` folder, where the `index.html` file is located that will be displayed at *https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME.github.io/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/*. The plugin will create a branch called "gh-pages" in your project that contains all files which are located in your www folder.
6. As a last step you have to select the "gh-page" branch in the settings of your project (*https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME.github.io/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/settings*) as a source for your github page.

You can also set different branch names if you don't want to use the default "gh-pages" name (also master is possible, but then you should keep the source files in a different branch). Just run the plugin like this: `npx angular-cli-ghpages --branch=BRANCH-NAME --dir=www`.

Like [Gary Großgarten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9330080/gary-gro%C3%9Fgarten) suggested, you can create a script for it which makes it easier. For Ionic it would be: `ionic build --prod -- --base-href https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME.github.io/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/ && npx angular-cli-ghpages --branch=BRANCH-NAME --dir=www`

I was looking for a proper solution myself, credits go to [Juangui Jordán's](https://blog.mimacom.com/angular-cli-github-pages-stackblitz/) blog.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages to achieve this easily.

Just add

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "gh-pages": "ng build --base-href 'https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY_NAME/' --prod && npx ngh --dir=www/"
...
  }
```

to your package.json.

If you want a costum domain you can add the cname flag

```
--cname=example.com
```

to the ngh command.

To build and upload your site run

```
npm run gh-pages
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: For a *gitlab* repository (not Github) you can do this:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
pages:
 image: node:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - npm install -g ionic cordova
  - npm install
  # frontend application is served at https://what-digital.gitlab.io/stemba/
  # we need to set the basePath to the sub dir
  - ionic build --prod -- --base-href="https://what-digital.gitlab.io/gitlab-pages/"
  - rm -rf public
  - mkdir public
  - cp -r www/* public
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 week
  paths:
  - public
 only:
  - dev
```